# Faking 2d light using shader (Unity, Shaderlab)

Tags: 2d, unity, shaders, lighting, masking

[image]

Since the concept was difficult to explain in words for someone who's not quite familiar with shader, I described it in pictures.

I'm currently using Unity and it seems Shaderlab is the best choice to accomplish this.

To shader masters, this seems like quite a simple trick, but as beginner, I've been struggling to find right keywords and tutorials to accomplish this.

I wish someone could explain the concept behind this shader trick.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you can skip some of the textures, like *"Black"*, which looks like an uniform color, or the *"Character (dark)"* which isn't needed since you can get this information from the characters alpha-channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique is called masking. Alpha is used as a mask to calculate how much of the original pixel's color gets in to the final image.